# How to get last extract time of tableau workbooks using python

Tags: python, metadata, tableau-api

I need to list down the last refresh time of tableau workbooks

I'm able to get other details of the workbook by reading metadata query for upstream data sources and embedded data sources, but I need last extract time of the workbook not the data sources

```
{
  "workbooks": {
    "name": "",
    "luid": "",
    "project name": "",
    "CreatedAt": "",
    "updatedAt": ""
  },
  "UpstreamDatasources": {
    "name": "",
    "extractLastRefreshTime": ""
  },
  "embedded data sources": {
    "name": "",
    "extractLastRefreshTime": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you establish a connection to Tableau Server API or Tableau Workgroups Database you will be able to extract that information using the views_stats table.

You can find the documentation [here](https://tableau.github.io/tableau-data-dictionary/2019.4/data_dictionary.htm#views_stats_anchor)